# Need ideas on Version number position for web application

Tags: website-design, users, position, versioning

I want the user to notice the version number as it will be easy during feedback. There is no footer and menus for the website.

[image: app mockup]

I am planning to put it under the logo as shown above. Need comments on same. Any examples would help.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider whether the version number is important to users at all times.

If it is just for feedback, include it in your feedback form, otherwise don't put it anywhere.

Comment: I agree, context is key.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have neither a footer nor a menu I think your positioning is just about right. I would consider however placing the version alongside the logo or right beneath it and left aligned. I would also consider making version lowercase.

[image: Basecamp 3 screenshot]

Basecamp's marketing pages feature their current product version in almost the same way as you do. But it's clear that this is for product marketing's sake and does not carry over to the actual interface of the application.

If you would like to be more economical with the space you allot to this information you can truncate the number (e.g. LOGO 1.2, where the version is alongside the logo) and reveal the full description as a tooltip upon hover (e.g. you are using version 1.2.3.4 of this site).